# Function is exiting loop too early

Tags: c++, for-loop, brute-force

I'm given a vector of ints, in which each number represents a color of socks. I know the most optimal solution would to be use a hash set but I'm trying to do the brute force method just to mess around. However, my loops begin to act funny after finding the 3rd pair, as it leaves the inner loop and the control flow never comes back in. In fact, even the outside loop stops prematurely despite i being less than n.

I've tried tracing using a debugger, but I'm confused because i nor j ever exceeds n but yet it stops. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int sockMerchant(int n, vector<int> ar) {
    int pair = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n - 1; j++) {
            if (ar[i] == ar[j] && ar[i] > 0) {
                pair++;
                ar[i] = 0;
                ar[j] = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return pair;
}


int main() {
    vector<int> vec = {4,5,5,5,6,6,4,1,4,4,3,6,6,3,6,1,4,5,5,5};
    int n = 9;

    cout << sockMerchant(n, vec);

}
```

My approach for the brute force is to turn matching pairs into zeroes as being visited already. The constraints is that the sock colors are between 1 to 100. If you find a matching pair that is not zero, then increment the pair counter by 1, and return pair when the loops are done.

Comment: What is the expected result? And why is `n` 9? What does `n` represent? Is it supposed to be the size of the vector?

Comment: There are only three pairs within the first eight elements. You want to loop over the entire vector instead of just the first `n-1` elements.

Comment: I see that you used n to get the size of the vector. Instead you can just use ar.size(). This makes the code more readable and also you won't have to change the n variable every time that you change the size of the vector.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing an argument `n` which is equal to 9. However, you are using this value as the loop bound of the `vector` in your `for` loops, which is incorrect.

Instead, you can simply pass the `vector` to the function (by reference to avoid a copy), and compute the bounds there:

```
int sockMerchant(vector<int>& ar) {
    int n = ar.size();
    // ...
```

and call it like this:

```
cout << sockMerchant(vec);
```

Also, your loop counters don't go far enough. The condition should be `i < n`, instead of `i < n - 1`.

These fixes give a result of 9, which is the number of matching pairs in the input vector. Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/34sf9a).

Answer (score 0):

> In fact, even the outside loop stops prematurely despite i being less than n.

In my tests, the loop breaks when `i` reaches the value of 8, which make sense given your conditional - `i < n - 1`. Perhaps you meant to use `i < n`.

It's useful to print diagnostic output when you are not sure what's happening. See https://ideone.com/sR56AH.

Useful link: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).